# Having trouble with pandas

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

```
import pandas as pd 

stack = pd.DataFrame(['adam',25,28,'steve',25,28,'emily',18,21)
print(stack[0].to_list()[0::2]) 
print(stack[0].to_list()[1::2]) 
df = pd.DataFrame(
{'Name': stack[0].to_list()[0::3], 
'Age': stack[0].to_list()[1::3], 
'New Age': stack[0].to_list()[2::3] }
) 

print(df)
```

It how do i separate adam and steve into a different row?
I want it to line up like the table below.

[Table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rLhhL.png)

Comment: on image you had different table

Comment: Please post a good question as per [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20109391/how-to-make-good-reproducible-pandas-examples). You must provide examples of what you are getting and what you want to be getting.

Comment: don't change original question. Now our answers doesn't fit to your question. If you have new problem then create new question on new page.

Comment: you forgot `]` in lin `pd.DataFrame(['adam',25,28,'steve',25,28,'emily',18,21])` and it is all your problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can get it as list and use slice `[0::2]` and `[1::2]`

```
import pandas as pd

data = pd.DataFrame(['adam',22,'steve',25,'emily',18])

print(data)
#print(data[0].to_list()[0::2])
#print(data[0].to_list()[1::2])

df = pd.DataFrame({
    'Name': data[0].to_list()[0::2],
    'Age': data[0].to_list()[1::2],
})

print(df)
```

Before (like on original image which was removed from question)

```
       0
0   adam
1     22
2  steve
3     25
4  emily
5     18
```

After:

```
    Name  Age
0   adam   22
1  steve   25
2  emily   18
```

---

**EDIT:** image from original question

[image]

---

**EDIT:** BTW: the same with normal list

```
import pandas as pd

data = ['adam',22,'steve',25,'emily',18]

print(data)

df = pd.DataFrame({
    'Name': data[0::2],
    'Age': data[1::2],
})

print(df)
```

Comment: import pandas as pd
    
    stack = pd.DataFrame(['adam',25,28,'steve',25,28,'emily',18,21)
    
    print(stack[0].to_list()[0::2])
    print(stack[0].to_list()[1::2])
    
    df = pd.DataFrame({
        'Name': stack[0].to_list()[0::3],
        'Age': stack[0].to_list()[1::3],
        'New Age': stack[0].to_list()[2::3]
    })
    
    print(df)

i ran this but im confused as why it doesn't work

Comment: you forgot `]` in  `pd.DataFrame([...])`

Answer (score 0):

These two lines should do it. However, without knowing what code you have, what you're trying to accomplish, or what else you intend to do with it, the following code is only valid in this situation.

```
d = {'Name': ['adam', 'steve', 'emily'], 'Age': [22, 25, 18]}
df = pd.DataFrame(d)
```

Comment: The other answer is more robust, and will work in all cases where your original data (the left table) is able to be converted into a pandas dataframe.